# com.sun.mail.iap.protocolexception no login methods supported

Tags: linux, email, email-server, dovecot, imap

A JavaMail app and dovecot/postfix/mutt are running on the same CentOS 7 physical serverbox.  This JavaMail app was able to reliably import emails via IMAP using the same exact code until some changes were made on the server  [using instructions from this OpenVPN tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7).  Now, the following error is being thrown when the app tries to connect via IMAP:

```
com.sun.mail.iap.protocolexception no login methods supported
```

**How can I alter the server configuration to allow IMAP connections again?** For the record, `dovecot.conf` does indeed include `protocols = imap pop3`

The line of code that throws the error is:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore();
store.connect("host", "user", "password*");//this line throws the error
```

The complete stack trace is:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: No login methods supported!;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.ProtocolException: No login methods supported!
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:668)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at com.hpp.kp.web.HL7PatientController.processInbox(HL7PatientController.java:1371)
    at com.hpp.kp.web.HL7PatientController.processEmailInbox(HL7PatientController.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandl$
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandl$
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAd$
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java$
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRe$
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationPro$
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:$
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerI$
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:831)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.ProtocolException: No login methods supported!
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.login(IMAPStore.java:745)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:642)
    ... 88 more
```

**EDIT#1**

As per MikeB's suggestion, `telnet mydomain.com 143` results in:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED] Dovecot ready.
```

**EDIT#2**

Adding `session.setDebug(true);` resulted in the following additional information being printed before the stack trace:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0-b01
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.partialfetch: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "mydomain.com", port 143, isSSL false
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED] Dovecot ready.
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=mydomain.com, user=username, password=<non-null>
```

The same stack trace as above follows immediately after these new debug messages.

**EDIT#3**

As per @masgaloeh's suggestion, I typed `dovecot -n` and the terminal replied with the following:

```
# 2.2.10: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.10.0-123.13.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64 CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)  
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {special_use = \Drafts}
  mailbox Junk {special_use = \Junk}
  mailbox Sent {special_use = \Sent}
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {special_use = \Sent}
  mailbox Trash {special_use = \Trash}
  prefix = 
}
passdb {driver = pam}
protocols = imap pop3
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {driver = passwd}
```

**Does this help you isolate the solution?**

Comment: How you tried both plain text IMAP (obviously not appropriate for any end user activity or insecure networks).  I suspect that the issue might be SSL related since the prior tutorial adjusted that.

Comment: @MikeB How would I try plain text IMAP?  Does that involve changing config files or changing the JavaMail code? And what would that accomplish?  These emails will be encrypted when they are received, and will be decrypted using my Java code.  Server has to be extremely secure.

Comment: Please see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug and https://community.oracle.com/message/9334525#9334525

Comment: Try enable debug `session.setDebug(true);` to get more information.

Comment: @FedericoSierra Please see **EDIT#2** with results of `session.setDebug(true);`  Does this help you isolate the problem?

Comment: @MikeB I added `session.setDebug(true);` and posted the results in **EDIT#2** at the end of my OP.  Does this help you isolate the problem?

Comment: Post the output of command `dovecot -n`. Probably there are misconfiguration in dovecot side

Comment: @masegaloeh Please see my **EDIT#3** with the results of `dovecot -n`.  Is there anything else that I can provide to help you identify the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dovecot -n output`, looks like you have enabled 'ssl-enforcing' mode

```
ssl = required
```

The result is here the dovecot output when telnet 127.0.0.1 143

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED] Dovecot ready.
```

With 'ssl-enforcing' mode, IMAP client (javamail code) must issuing STARTTLS command before doing login. From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10442877/3604386), looks like you have to enabled starttls mode in JavaMail. So maybe you have to add this piece of code.

```
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true")
```

Comment: What about the part of the log fragment you quote that states `LOGINDISABLED` for dovecot.  How do I fix that?

Comment: LOGINDISABLED was result of ssl-enforcing mode above and the parameter [#disable_plaintext_auth = yes](http://www.dovecot.org/doc/dovecot-example.conf).
 After telnet, you must issuing STARTTLS first then doing some SSL negotiation ritual. After secure connection was established, the AUTH will work.

Comment: Thank you.  I think you just said that adding `prop.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true")` would enable AUTH to work, and that you did not give further instructions.  I did this, but am getting another downstream error.  I would like to wait to mark this answer as accepted until enough of the downstream is resolved for me to feel confident.  Are you willing to help me with the next error?  Here is a link to a posting about it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521266/caused-by-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to

Comment: I only have little experience with java. See the [stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442877/java-mail-to-exchange-server-no-login-methods-supported) in my answer above to help you debug java issue (including certificate issue)

Comment: OK.  Thank you.  +1 for your time and attention.  I will come back later to do housekeeping like marking accepted answers, etc.

Comment: Hi @CodeMed , did you still have this issue? Is there any changes in dovecot configuration beside my answer above?

Comment: I did have to make other changes to make this work.  Let me try to remember what they were. The generalized issue was that the OpenVPN setup caused the server to be a lot less tolerant of vagueness, so that a number of different things had to be stated explicitly instead of taken for granted. This included database configs, security certificates, etc. But I will have to think about what affected this and get back to you when I remember. The issue might have been resolved by explicitly registering security certificates with Java. But I will have to think if that was what fixed this issue.

Comment: Yep thanks for remembering. Please put your additional/complete answer in another answer box below :)